# Custom Post Type Submenu

Tags: wordpress, admin

Is there a way of adding a sub menu on and admin menu (plugin) and this particular menu is a custom post type?

Here's the code:

```
// The Main Menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'create_main_menu' );
function create_main_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'Menu Title', 
        'Menu Name', 
        'manage_options', 
        'menuslughere', 
        'display_custom_page' 
    ); 
}
function display_custom_page(){ 
    include 'sample_page.php'; 
}

// The Submenu
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_custom_post_type' );
function create_my_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'post_type_name',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Sample',
            'menu_name' => 'Sample',
                'singular_name' => 'Sample',
                'add_new' => 'Sample',
                'add_new_item' => 'Sample',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Sample',
                'new_item' => 'New Sample',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Sample',
                'search_items' => 'Search Sample',
                'not_found' => 'No Sample found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sample found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'sample_parent'
            ),             
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=menuslughere',
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
```

If you'll check the code, the registering of post type part... I have supplied the show_in_menu with "admin.php?page=menuslughere" but it seems it is not working.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want the custom post type link be under a admin menu (custom)

Comment: Try `'show_in_menu' => 'menuslughere'` instead of `'show_in_menu' => 'admin.php?page=menuslughere'`. It should work since WordPress 3.5+ but in my case it's overriding the parent's menu URL for some reason...